# Can't use Variable Inside Async Function?

Tags: javascript, async-await

So, I know this must be a pretty dumb question but am not great in javascript,
so I'm trying to insert Tradingview free widget on my site but the problem is I can't use the variable inside it because of its async function.

here is code

```
<script>var coinName = "XRP"</script>
```

so I'm using 2 scripts from Tradingview, first one is this and its working perfectly fine.

```
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_8e4c9"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "BINANCE:" + coinName + "USD",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "dark",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "en",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_8e4c9"

}
  );
  </script>
</div>
```

this is the second code, I'm trying to do exactly same as  the script above but its not working

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Technical Analysis for BTCUSD</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
  {
  "interval": "1M",
  "width": 425,
  "isTransparent": false,
  "height": 450,
  "symbol": "BINANCE:" + coinName + "USD",
  "showIntervalTabs": true,
  "locale": "en",
  "colorTheme": "dark",
  "largeChartUrl": "http://#"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

second code gives 2 error in console,

Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token + in JSON at position 105

and

Invalid settings provided, fall back to defaults

so how can I achieve that?

Comment: *What* variable exactly and how "can't" you use it?

Comment: *"i want to pass coinName here"* - What happens when you try?

Comment: Please add the following information: 
1) The name async function.
2) name of the variable you're trying to use.
3) how and where are you using the variable?

Comment: Why do you have both text content and src attribute in the same script tag?

Comment: Got it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3s5rn1bg/

Comment: A `script` element is not supposed to have both a `src`, _and_ text content between the tags. In such a situation, only the code from the external script file will get executed - if that script wants to do anything with the text contained between the tags, it has to fetch that out of the DOM itself. Assuming that is the case here, it means you will have to create the whole script element dynamically - with the `src` attribute set, and a text node appended to it. Since that text node will be created from a string value, you are free to insert any variable value you like, dynamically.

Comment: @qrsngky The script is loading its own element's innerText and parsing it. This is common for widgets.

Comment: #qrsngky #CBroe I don't, it's widget from Tradingview so i just copy pasted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CrisG s answer solved this issue

> Got it to work: jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/3s5rn1bg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).